# Fill area below geom_curve in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my code:

```
ggplot(data = tibble(x = 1:20, y = 1:20),
       aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  
  geom_curve(x = 10, y = 7.55, xend = 15, yend = 7.6,
             curvature = .28, size = .7250, color  ='black')+
  
  geom_point()
```

How can I fill the area below this curve? Between `x = 10` and `x = 12` and **considering the `ymax` being the curve**.

Comment: `geom_curve` doesn't really have the notion (or `aes`thetic) of "fill", I suggest you create the curve data beforehand and use `geom_polygon`.

Comment: Nice @r2evans! How can I extract the curve data? How this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to extract `geom_curve`'s internal data produced during rendering, but here's a method:

```r
gg <- ggplot(data = tibble(x = 1:20, y = 1:20),
       aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_curve(x = 10, y = 7.55, xend = 15, yend = 7.6,
             curvature = .28, size = .7250, color  ='black')+
  geom_point()
```

We'll produce a curve on our own. I'm using `51` here just to get many points; you may want fewer or more depending on the size of your curve and the resolution of your eventual plot.

```r
curvedat <- data.frame(x = seq(10, 15, len = 51))
curvedat$y <- with(curvedat, 4 + 5*abs((x - 10) / 5 - 0.5)^2)
gg + geom_path(data = curvedat)
```

[image: ggplot with second curve, for testing/validation]

(The two curves are shown together here in order to demonstrate their similarity. There's no assumption of maintaining the original curve in the plot. Also, the second curve is shown offset down, I'm assuming you would address that in your suitability decision.)

Once you have a curve that looks okay, then wrap two "low" points around it and add as a polygon:

```r
gg +
  geom_polygon(data = rbind(
    data.frame(x = min(curvedat$x), y = -Inf),
    curvedat,
    data.frame(x = max(curvedat$x), y = -Inf)
  ))
```

[image: ggplot2 with curve converted to a polygon]

Comment: Amazing @r2evans. Thanks for your time!